# Adding MKOverlayPathRenderer as overlay to MKMapView gets exception

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay, mkoverlaypathrenderer

Everything said in topic, so here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     _pathRenderer = [[MKOverlayPathRenderer alloc] init];
     _pathRenderer.lineWidth = 8.0f;
     _pathRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
     _pathRenderer.path = CGPathCreateMutable();
     [_mapView addOverlay:_pathRenderer];
}
```

At the last line it drops with exception:

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKOverlayPathRenderer boundingMapRect]: unrecognized selector
```

It means that i'm using wrong class that don't implements MKOverlay, I got it, but as said in reference of MKOverlayPathRenderer - it does. So I'm a bit stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MKOverlayPathRenderer` does not implement the `MKOverlay` protocol.

The `addOverlay` requires an object that conforms to the `MKOverlay` protocol.

The object you're giving it doesn't do that and so you get that exception (objects that implement `MKOverlay` must have a `boundingMapRect` property).

In your question, the statement:

> as said in reference of MKOverlayPathRenderer - it does

doesn't make sense.

The documentation does not say that `MKOverlayPathRenderer` implements `MKOverlay`.  `MKOverlayPathRenderer` is a subclass of `MKOverlayRenderer` and `NSObject`.  It conforms only to the `NSObject` protocol.

An `MKOverlayPathRenderer` draws the *visual* representation of some *model* overlay object that conforms to `MKOverlay`.

So there are two separate objects required (similar to how annotations work):

1. The *model* of the overlay -- something that implements `MKOverlay`.
2. The *view* of the overlay -- some subclass of `MKOverlayRenderer` (or `MKOverlayView` before iOS 7).

The procedure is to first give the `MKMapView` the *model* object(s) using the `addOverlay:` or `addOverlays:` methods.

Then in the `rendererForOverlay` delegate method, which the map view will call when it actually wants to display some overlay, you create and return a *renderer* (*view*) for the overlay in question.

The code you have that creates a renderer would normally be in the `rendererForOverlay` delegate method and should use the `initWithOverlay` method (instead of `init`) and should pass the `overlay` model object for which you want to create the renderer.

For the `addOverlay`, you would create some overlay model object -- either some standard class like `MKPolyline`, `MKPolygon`, `MKCircle`, or a custom class.

**But are you sure you need an `MKOverlayPathRenderer`?**

If you just want to draw a simple line, circle, or polygon, use the renderers already provided that automatically draw these objects for you.  You will have a much easier time than creating your own subclass of `MKOverlayPathRenderer`.

`MKPolylineRenderer`, `MKPolygonRenderer`, and `MKCircleRenderer` are built-in subclasses of `MKOverlayPathRenderer` that draw their related model overlays without you writing any drawing code.

Comment: Thanks, I already changed to  MKPolylineRenderer. I'm new to iOS - that's why I did such obvious mistake) I thought that MKOverlayRenderer implements MKOverlay, and than I understood the difference. But anyway, thx again)

Comment: Anna. Could you please have a look at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801822/swift-draw-a-semi-sphere-in-mkmapview. Many thanks!