# How to use MKPolylineView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkpolyline

I want to draw polyline in my Swift app.

Swift code

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var theMapView: MKMapView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setMapView()
    }

    func setMapView() {
        //theMapView.zoomEnabled = false
        //theMapView.scrollEnabled = false 
        theMapView.rotateEnabled = false  

        // 
        var lat: CLLocationDegrees = 37.586601
        var lng: CLLocationDegrees = 127.009381

        // 
        var latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.008
        var lngDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.008

        var theSpan: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lngDelta)

        var initLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
        var theRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(initLocation, theSpan)
        self.theMapView.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)

        var locations = [CLLocation(latitude: 37.582691, longitude: 127.011186), CLLocation(latitude: 37.586112,longitude: 127.011047), CLLocation(latitude: 37.588212, longitude: 127.010438)]
        var coordinates = locations.map({(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate})
        var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: locations.count)

        var myPolylineView : MKPolylineView
        /* error */
        myPolylineView.polyline = polyline // #1
        myPolylineView.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor() // #2
        myPolylineView.lineWidth = 5; // #3
        self.theMapView.addOverlay(myPolylineView) // #4
        /* ----- */    
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
// #1 <br>
Cannot assign to 'polyline' in 'myPolylineView' <br>
// #2 <br>
'strokeColor' is unvailable: APIs deprecated as iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift <br>
// #3 <br>
'lineWidth' is unvailable: APIs deprecated as iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift <br>
// #4 <br>
Missing argument for parameter 'level' in call <br>
```

I cannot find a solution to this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**First**, instead of `MKPolylineView`, you must create an `MKPolylineRenderer`.

`MKPolylineView` has been deprecated since iOS 7 and, although you can still use it in Objective-C if necessary, it's not supported in Swift.

**Second**, you must create and return an `MKPolylineRenderer` in the `rendererForOverlay` delegate method (not pass it to `addOverlay`).

In the `addOverlay` method, you pass the `MKPolyline` object (not the `MKPolylineView` or `MKPolylineRenderer`).

(See [Adding MKOverlayPathRenderer as overlay to MKMapView gets exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755462/adding-mkoverlaypathrenderer-as-overlay-to-mkmapview-gets-exception) for an explanation of the difference between what object you pass to `addOverlay` vs. what object you return in `rendererForOverlay`.)

So in the `setMapView` method, remove the lines that create and set `myPolylineView` and change the `addOverlay` line to:

```
self.theMapView.addOverlay(polyline)
```

Then implement the `rendererForOverlay` method:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5
        return polylineRenderer
    }

    return nil
}
```

Make sure the map view's `delegate` is set otherwise the delegate method won't get called and the overlay will not appear.  If `theMapView` is an IBOutlet, connect the `delegate` outlet or set it in code (eg. in `viewDidLoad` after calling super):

```
self.theMapView.delegate = self
```

Comment: @VanDuTran, make sure of the following: 1) Map view outlet is connected, 2) Map view delegate is connected/set, 3) rendererForOverlay method is spelled correctly.  If still not called, please ask a new Question with your details.

Comment: It's because my geojson has some weird coordinates: "coordinates":[[294636.0501,5039009.536],[294572.3566,5039049.88]]