# Overlay MKPolyLine issue in MKMapView (rendererForOverLay)

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, core-location, mkpolyline

I'm trying to add a polyline for a route on MapView from location A to location B (which is the current user's GPS location), so the route/polyline would be able to follow from a set location A to wherever the user is current at (location B) on the fly.

Right now my overlay is not working. I looked at a few other SO threads on [MKPolylineView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798737/how-to-use-mkpolylineview-in-swift), but when I tried implementing their code (which is below as well) the route/lines are still not showing. I'm new to iOS, so I'm still familiarizing with Swift/mapKit myself.

Here is what I have so far: (modified to show important parts)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var setLocButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
var carLat = 36.136111, carLong = -80.279462


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]!) { //AnyObject->CLLocation
    var latestLocation: CLLocation = locations[locations.count - 1]

    //Displaying location A on mapView
    let carCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: carLat, longitude: carLong)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: carCoords, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0035, longitudeDelta: 0.0035))
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    //Attempting to display route information on mapView
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    var locations = [CLLocation(latitude: carLat, longitude: carLong), CLLocation(latitude: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)]
    var coordinates = locations.map({(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate})
    var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: locations.count)

    self.mapView.addOverlay(polyline)

}

//rendererForOverlay
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolyline {

        /* Does not get called */
        print("rendererForOverlay") 

        var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5
        return polylineRenderer
    }
    return nil
}
```

I also found [another example using MKDirections](http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2014/10/mkdirections-draw-route-from-location.html), which seems to be more ideal because it allows me to set the transport type (MKDirectionsTransportType.Walking). I'm having problem drawing the routes with those instructions too though.

Using the second set of instructions, here is what I got after resolving some errors Xcode alerted me of:

```
var route: MKRoute?

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]!) { //AnyObject->CLLocation
    var latestLocation: CLLocation = locations[locations.count - 1] //AnyObject

    /* 
    ...
    */

    //carLocation = Location A; currentLocation = location B
    var directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    let carLocation = MKPlacemark(coordinate: carCoords, addressDictionary: nil) 
    var currentLocation = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coorLat, longitude: coorLong), addressDictionary: nil)

    directionsRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: currentLocation)
    directionsRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: carLocation)
    directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Walking

    var directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)
    directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler {
        (response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.route = response!.routes[0] as? MKRoute
            self.mapView.addOverlay((self.route?.polyline)!)
        }
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {

    /* Does not get executed as well */
    print("RendererForOverLay")

    var myLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: (route?.polyline)!)
    myLineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
    myLineRenderer.lineWidth = 3
    return myLineRenderer
}
```

Am I somehow linking the rendererForOverlay wrong, since it is not called in both instances?

Comment: Did you set the class that contains the `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer!` as delegate for your mapView? As it is done in `func viewDidLoad` in the example of your link? That code: `myMap.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sofacoder is right, the polyline renderer works now!

I forgot to add **myMap.delegate = self** in my function, and also omitted **MKMapViewDelegate** the ViewController's declaration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
```